# Symfony - Guzzle return error when registering at yml

Tags: php, symfony, guzzle

I'm using Symfony 2.7 with Guzzle 5.3.

My services.yml :

```
    ma_api.client:
    class: 'GuzzleHttp\Client'
```

And my error is :

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "No method can handle the client config key" at /home/vsilvestre/Projets/front-mobileangelo/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Message/MessageFactory.php line 360 {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): No method can handle the client config key at /home/vsilvestre/Projets/front-mobileangelo/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Message/MessageFactory.php:360)"} []

If someone is able to help me .. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was "easy".

My problem was at my request, not the registering.

```
$this->get('ma_api.client')->post('v2/leads', [
                'eukera' => 'client'
            ]);
```

The option isn't body anymore, it's options that need to be build like 'body' => [content]

I close it. (Thanks for edits.)